# How is poky platform independent

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I am trying to understand poky in yocto project. Many places it is written that poky is platform independent.. can you guys please explain me what does this mean. Does it mean that it can run on any Linux .

Link which says this:

https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application_development/9781783282333/1/ch01lvl1sec10/understanding-poky

Comment: provide links ?

Comment: https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application_development/9781783282333/1/ch01lvl1sec10/understanding-poky

Comment: Please edit the question directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it mean that it can run on any Linux .

No, Poky itself is a minimal Linux distribution used for demonstration purposes.

What they mean by platform independent is most likely the architecture of the target for which poky will be compiled. (i.g. armhf, amd64, qemu, etc..)